# Iterate over HTMLCollection in custom element

Tags: javascript, html, shadow-dom, custom-element

How can I iterate over instances of one custom element within the shadow dom of another custom element? HTMLCollections don't seem to behave as expected. (I'm a jQuerian and a novice when it comes to vanilla js, so I'm sure I'm making an obvious error somewhere).

**HTML**

```html
<spk-root>
  <spk-input></spk-input>
  <spk-input></spk-input>
</spk-root>
```

**Custom Element Definitions**

For `spk-input`:

```js
class SpektacularInput extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}
window.customElements.define('spk-input', SpektacularInput);
```

For `spk-root`:

```js
let template = document.createElement('template');
template.innerHTML = `
  <canvas id='spektacular'></canvas>
  <slot></slot>
`;

class SpektacularRoot extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    let shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
  }
  update() {
    let inputs = this.getElementsByTagName('spk-input')
  }
  connectedCallback() {
    this.update();
  }
}
window.customElements.define('spk-root', SpektacularRoot);
```

---

Here's the part I don't understand. Inside the `update()` method:
`console.log(inputs)` returns an HTMLCollection:

```js
console.log(inputs)

// output
HTMLCollection []
  0: spk-input
  1: spk-input
  length: 2
  __proto__: HTMLCollection
```

However, the HTMLCollection is not iterable using a `for` loop, because it has no length.

```
console.log(inputs.length)

// output
0
```

Searching SO revealed that HTMLCollections are array-like, but not arrays. Trying to make it an array using `Array.from(inputs)` or the spread operator results in an empty array.

What's going on here? How can I iterate over the `spk-input` elements within `spk-root` from the `update()` method?

I'm using gulp-babel and gulp-concat and using Chrome. Let me know if more info is needed. Thanks in advance.

---

**Edit**: To clarify, calling `console.log(inputs.length)` from **within** the `update()` outputs `0` instead of `2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason will be that `connectedCallback()` of a custom element in certain cases will be called as soon as the browser meets the **opening tag** of the custom element, **with children not being parsed, and thus, unavailable**. This does e.g. happen in Chrome if you define the elements up front and the browser then parses the HTML.

That is why `let inputs = this.getElementsByTagName('spk-input')` in your `update()` method of the outer `<spk-root>` cannot find any elements. Don't let yourself be fooled by misleading console.log output there.

I've just recently taken a deep dive into this topic, and suggested a solution using a `HTMLBaseElement` class:

> https://gist.github.com/franktopel/5d760330a936e32644660774ccba58a7

Andrea Giammarchi (the author of `document-register-element` polyfill for custom elements in non-supporting browsers) has taken on that solution suggestion and created an npm package from it:

> https://github.com/WebReflection/html-parsed-element

As long as you don't need dynamic creation of your custom elements, the easiest and most reliable fix is to create the **upgrade** scenario by putting your element defining scripts at the end of the `body`.

If you're interested in the discussion on the topic (long read!):

> https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/551

Here's the full gist:

## HTMLBaseElement class solving the problem of connectedCallback being called before children are parsed

There is a huge practical problem with web components spec v1:

In certain cases `connectedCallback` is being called when the element's child nodes are not yet available.

This makes web components dysfunctional in those cases where they rely on their children for setup.

See https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/551 for reference.

To solve this, we have created a `HTMLBaseElement` class in our team which serves as the new class to extend autonomous custom elements from.

`HTMLBaseElement` in turn inherits from `HTMLElement` (which autonomous custom elements must derive from at some point in their prototype chain).

`HTMLBaseElement` adds two things:

- a `setup` method that takes care of the correct timing (that is, makes sure child nodes are accessible) and then calls `childrenAvailableCallback()` on the component instance.
- a `parsed` Boolean property which defaults to `false` and is meant to be set to `true` when the components initial setup is done. This is meant to serve as a guard to make sure e.g. child event listeners are never attached more than once.

### HTMLBaseElement

```
class HTMLBaseElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor(...args) {
    const self = super(...args)
    self.parsed = false // guard to make it easy to do certain stuff only once
    self.parentNodes = []
    return self
  }

  setup() {
    // collect the parentNodes
    let el = this;
    while (el.parentNode) {
      el = el.parentNode
      this.parentNodes.push(el)
    }
    // check if the parser has already passed the end tag of the component
    // in which case this element, or one of its parents, should have a nextSibling
    // if not (no whitespace at all between tags and no nextElementSiblings either)
    // resort to DOMContentLoaded or load having triggered
    if ([this, ...this.parentNodes].some(el=> el.nextSibling) || document.readyState !== 'loading') {
      this.childrenAvailableCallback();
    } else {
      this.mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(() => {
        if ([this, ...this.parentNodes].some(el=> el.nextSibling) || document.readyState !== 'loading') {
          this.childrenAvailableCallback()
          this.mutationObserver.disconnect()
        }
      });

      this.mutationObserver.observe(this, {childList: true});
    }
  }
}
```

Example component extending the above:

```
class MyComponent extends HTMLBaseElement {
  constructor(...args) {
    const self = super(...args)
    return self
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    // when connectedCallback has fired, call super.setup()
    // which will determine when it is safe to call childrenAvailableCallback()
    super.setup()
  }

  childrenAvailableCallback() {
    // this is where you do your setup that relies on child access
    console.log(this.innerHTML)
    
    // when setup is done, make this information accessible to the element
    this.parsed = true
    // this is useful e.g. to only ever attach event listeners once
    // to child element nodes using this as a guard
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The HTMLCollection `inputs` does have a length property, and if you log it inside the update function you will see it's value is 2. You can also iterate through the inputs collection in a for loop so long as it's inside the update() function.

If you want to access the values in a loop outside of the update function, you can store the HTMLCollection in a variable declared outside of the scope of the SpektacularInput class.

I suppose there are other ways to store the values depending on what you're trying to accomplish, but hopefully this answers your initial question "How can I iterate over the spk-input elements within spk-root from the update() method?"

```js
class SpektacularInput extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}
window.customElements.define('spk-input', SpektacularInput);
let template = document.createElement('template');
template.innerHTML = `
  <canvas id='spektacular'></canvas>
  <slot></slot>
`;
// declare outside variable
let inputsObj = {};
class SpektacularRoot extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    let shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
  }
  update() {
    // store on outside variable
    inputsObj = this.getElementsByTagName('spk-input');
    // use in the function
    let inputs = this.getElementsByTagName('spk-input');
    console.log("inside length: " + inputs.length)
    for(let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
      console.log("inside input " + i + ": " + inputs[i]);
    }
  }
  connectedCallback() {
    this.update();
  }
}
window.customElements.define('spk-root', SpektacularRoot);

console.log("outside length: " + inputsObj.length);
for(let i = 0; i < inputsObj.length; i++){
  console.log("outside input " + i + ": " + inputsObj[i]);
}
```

```html
<spk-root>
  <spk-input></spk-input>
  <spk-input></spk-input>
</spk-root>
```

Hope it helps,
Cheers!